# three20 TTTabBar performance?

Tags: iphone, three20, tabbar

I used TTTabBar in the [Three20](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three20) library. It seems to be a good simulator. But its scroll speed is significantly slower in the device (iPhone 4).

All I did was just replacing few names in it. So I was curious if maybe I did something wrong. So I tried the sample project provided by the library. And it's slow too!

How to use it not slowly?

I think the TTTabBar is used in the 'USA TODAY' app. It almost looks the same, but it's not slow. There must be a way.

Answer (score 0):

It can also depend on the content which you are going to load (meaning web content), images from the web service in to the scrollview.

Or maybe you have provided the animation to the component within the scrollview. Check it out.

If it is animation then give minimum animation time as the device can not respond fast to touch or gesture as in the simulator.

Is three20 Library free of cost? I have one for a PDF book to turn the pages like with gesture (how can we know that particular library is free of cost?).

Answer (score 0):

Try to load all your content in the initWithNibName method. (e.g. Parse websites, load images)

That was the solution for me because the content is loaded when the app starts up.